# Correlation with ordered categories (ordinal data with many ties)

Tags: correlation, anova, pearson-r, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

I want to compute a correlation between two variables in SPSS (n = 300). Variable A (income per year) is clearly interval scaled, and I need help defining Variable B and chosing the correct correlation coefficient  or other test statistic.

Variable B is the number of vacations taken in a year, and in my dataset it takes on values between 1 and 5 (1,2,3,4,5). So I am wondering if this variable is 
a) interval,
b) ordinal with very many tied ranks,
c) categorical with ordered categories.

And which correlation (or alternative) should I use, depending on the scale?
a) Pearson 
b) Kendall-Tau/Spearman-Rho (can they deal with so many tied ranks??)
c) ??? (ANOVA would not take the order of the 5 categories into account; is there an alternative, maybe ANOVA with some kind of linear trend test?)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are the categories of your vacation variable naturally ordered, i.e. 1 = no vacations, 2 = some vacations, 5 = vacation all the time!!!!!!? Are they the actual number of vacations taken?

Comment: @Emma Jean: Yes they are the actual number of vacations taken.